# App deployed on PCF trying to find config at localhost:8888 even when the cloud foundry provided config server is binded with app

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

How do we make use of Spring Cloud Services like Config Services/ Hystrix at PCF? I have one app deployed on PCF and i am trying to bind a Config server service from CF marketplace to it. But when i start the app it tries to connect `localhost:8888`. Any Idea what can be done?

*manifest.yml*

```
---
applications:
- name: demo
  memory: 4096M
  host: demo
  domain: apps.pcf.devfg.***.com
  services:
  - ps-config-server-pcf
```

Comment: Are you using the Spring Cloud Services client libraries as documented at https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/client-dependencies.html?

Comment: Thankyou Scott, i missed those dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have these two Libraries in your `build.gradle` and the bind your App to the Marketplace service

```
io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server
```

Also, remove all your local configurations from your `bootstrap.yml` (however PCF will over ride your values, this is a good practice to do)

Comment: Hi Arun after using the above mentioned dependencies my app in PCf is trying to retrieve config from the Config server Cloud service Fetching config from server at  
   Logs        : https://config-****************-961dcfe83f58.apps.pcf.devfg.*****com  but getting : Could not resolve placeholder 'abc.var' in value "${abc.var}" .  controller:

Comment: There might be few mis-configurations within you setting the config server / git ... You can raise that as a separate question... However relevant to this topic, now its pointing to proper Config Server ... Please mark this as a Right Answer..

Comment: Thanks i have marke dthis right and will raise a separate question